# HTML5 canvas progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to draw a progress bar on HTML5 canvas while assets are loading, and I use this code:

```
Assets.Download(function(_loaded) {
    console.log("callback called");//its displayed in log
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, 0, _loaded * 500, 50);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#8ED6FF";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.stroke();
    sleep(1000);
})
```

`function(_loaded)` is called from `Download()`, and it works (I mean it's displaying in the log `"callback called"`, but the canvas is updated after the whole `Download()` ends. So all time I see nothing... and then the full bar :(

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

in javascript you can not listen for filedownload progress, the only thing you can listen for is file download completion

so if you have a list of N images when each finishes you could call the update progress bar but you cant do it for each byte that is downloaded

Comment: This is true for before-HTML5 browsers but does not stand for those with support.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can monitor download with the XMLHttpRequest Level 2 `progress` event. XHR2 is [supported](http://caniuse.com/xhr2) in most of the browsers that has a canvas with IE9 being an exception.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();


xhr.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {

    console.log(event.loaded / event.total);
},
false);
```